# Custom http error pages returns httpcode 200 (and not 404 or 500)

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, http-status-code-500

I am struggling with some custom error pages.

In my web.config I have the following which displays my error pages correctly:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
  <clear/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect" path="/system/not-found/" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="Redirect" path="/error.html" />
</httpErrors>
```

The 404 and 500 error pages are displayed correctly but using a program like Fiddler I can see that the pages return statusCode 200 even tough a 404 or 500 error has occurred. And this is a problem.

I have tried to change the existingResponse, responseMode and different combinations of those but no matter I try i will not work.

My question is: Am I doing something completely wrong regarding error pages? I must be missing something.

Comment: It may help a little if you specified the framework you are working with, and tagged appropriately, so the appropriate experts can find the question. It looks like .NET?